# Best practice for file upload before object is created?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, file-upload, jquery-file-upload

I got a form that has several steps and the first one is to upload an image (via carrierwave) which is supposed to happen in the background. So the server is receiving a file for an object that doesn't exist yet. So I'm wondering what's the best practice for this case?

I thought of two approaches:

- Make the image file a model that is created and returning the image ID upon upload completed.
- Create the object, having validations disabled and only the image saved returning the object ID and update it afterwards with validations on.

I'm leaning towards no. 1 but maybe one of you guys have an even better idea? Not happy creating a new model just for the image.

Answer (score 0):

`carrierwave` is a quality gem that will help you with your purposes. It doesn't require you to create a new model for image, rather you simply add an image field to one of your DB tables in `schema.rb`.

[Relevant Tutorial](http://railscasts.com/episodes/253-carrierwave-file-uploads)

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that I'm already using carrierwave and the gem itself works fine. The question is how to store the file before the object linked to it is created.